# Spring rest controller with @RequestBody and @RequestParam

Tags: spring, rest, spring-restcontroller

Hi I am trying to implement a rest post method where it will take a file as parameter and json body with some other details, below is the method syntax:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/v1/cust-advice", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> uploadFile(@RequestBody CustomerData custData,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
```

Can this be done in spring, if so how do I make a call to this method using postman.
I tried but got the error :Current request is not a multipart request

Comment: No as there is only 1 request body. Your `CustomerData` can just contain a field named `file` of type `MultipartFile` and it should be bound. If you want to bind individual parts of the body you could try using `@RequestPart` instead of `@RequestBody`.

Comment: Thanks @Deinum for the information, I need to modify my method i believe

Answer (score 2):

As @M.Deinum suggests, you can't send a file as a "parameter". Files are sent as one part of a multipart body, so `@RequestBody` would include everything (all parts) including the file.

Instead you can declare the JSON and the file as separate "parts" with `@RequestPart`:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = { "multipart/form-data" }, produces = "application/json")
public void upload(@RequestPart(name = "file", required = true) MultipartFile file,
        @RequestPart(name = "data", required = true) CustomerData data) {
```

Notice the `consumes` parameter of the `@PostMapping` and the `name` of both of the "parts".

In Postman select "form-data" under "Body". There add two entries with the same names as the `@RequestPart`s (in this example "file" and "data"). In the key column (a bit hidden) there is a selector where you can choose between "File" and "Text". When you choose "File", then a file selector appears in the value column. Paste the JSON into the value column of the "data" row.